# Copying backup Object seems to copy in reverse direction

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Finally had a problem that I can reproduce in small code. Result is in Console. Is the snippit background considered the same as Global?

Copying an array into Object (from [] format) works (first example), but (second example) setting one element of an array in it and then copying it to another object property seems to copy the property in reverse direction.

```js
var obj = {   //obj should be global, and the code below in a function,
    var1: [],
    var2: []  //But still same failure
}

obj.var1 = [1, 10, 1]; //first values
obj.var2 = obj.var1; //save backup globally in var2 between function calls
// ...
obj.var1 = [0, 2, 0]; //a new function call with new value in val1
// ...
obj.var1 = obj.var2; //and then overwrite and restore first values
console.log("1. This works: var1 = " + obj.var1 + ", var2 = " + obj.var2);
// both are [1,10,1] as expected

obj.var1[1] = 99;  //another new value, in one array index
// ...
obj.var1 = obj.var2; //and then restore first values again
console.log("2. Appears to copy the reverse  direction:\nvar1 = " + obj.var1 + ",  var2 = " + obj.var2);

//2.expects both var1 and var2 to be [1, 10, 1] but Both become [1, 99, 1] ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects and arrays in Javascript are reference type. When you are doing `obj.var1 = obj.var2;` it copies reference to `var1` and both `var1` and `var2` pointing to same object. When you update any of them, both are updated. To avoid that, you should do deep copy. Copy individual elements of your array to `var1`. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_objects#comparing_objects

If you copy elements instead of assigning whole array, it should work as expected.

```
obj.var1 = [...obj.var2]`
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew by reference, which gives it its speed. I imagined it would copy the contents at the address but I see now.  What is a deep copy?  Is that copying each individual property?

Comment: Yes it's a [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to copy elements of object or array.

Comment: But I have other instances where obj1 = obj2 seems to work. And this instance that fails is doing obj1.var1 = obj1.var2, so isnt that individual copies?

Comment: Not sure about other instances, here `obj.var1` is an array and when you assign to it another array (`obj.var2` in this case), both are pointing to same thing.

Comment: Is it only arrays? (also passed by reference).  I can't see any advantage of letting them become the same address.   Seems like design should have solved that.     Would obj,.var1 = n = obj.var2 be a way to solve it?   n would become the array, but hopefully its own address.

Comment: Both objects and arrays. ` obj,.var1 = n = obj.var2` would not work, since it is passing references.